# Missing copied file in destination folder using exec node in node-red flow

Tags: node.js, windows, node-red, file-copying

I'm trying to copy a file from one folder to another folder using node-red but flow execute fine and throwing an error and also showing syntax error in the console

My flow:

[image]

Node Configuration:

[image]

exec command used

```
copy C:\Users\Karthikeyan.Anbalaga\Downloads\ID_NewOnePulse_results.csv C:\Users\Karthikeyan.Anbalaga\Downloads\Documents\
```

At the same time if I execute the file copy command in the terminal working well

```
>copy C:\Users\Karthikeyan.Anbalaga\Downloads\ID_NewOnePulse_results.csv C:\Users\Karthikeyan.Anbalaga\Downloads\Documents\
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: Why are you appending the `msg.payload`? Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66838912/edit) the question to show the actual error message

Comment: Thanks, @hardillb it works fine after removing the msg.payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake on the configuration, after removing the `msg.payload` works fine and also files I can see in the destination folder.

[image]